# AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface

I am using GitHub CLI, when I run `gh gist edit <ID>`, it gives me this error:

```
 D:\lucas\Documents\Project\fork>gh gist edit 5366f5ac54b02086538313aa8133f660
'D:\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft' is not recognized as an internal or external,
 command, operable program or batch file.
 exit status 1
```

I don't know what is the problem. Please help, I'm new to GitHub CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gh gist edit` calls `gh config editor` and then find the match path in the Environment variable base on the command. For example, when you set `gh config set editor "code -w"`, scripts will find the path in environment variable base on the above command. So I assume you are using **Microsoft VS Code** path, `gh gist edit` actually searching for `bin` folder in `Microsoft VS Code`, so that means we have `Microsoft VS Code\bin`. And since it gives you `\Microsoft'` instead. Go to Environment Variable Path for VS Code to:

```
D:\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Code\bin
```

And then, in your local folder `D:\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`, change `Microsoft VS Code` to `Code`. After that, go to your favorite terminal and run the following command:

```
refreshenv
```

After refresh, open another terminal with Administrator rights. And run `gh gist edit`. And it should work.

Comment: It works, however, why should I run it administrator's right?